# Write stream to an java object, then use it to write to a file

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

I have the following schema in my design:

A class calls "step1 class". In step1 class, I'm accepting file upload. Then, later on, the caller class calls some other classes and at the end of these steps, I would like to store the file that is uploaded in the first step.

Here is the code:

```
public final class Caller{

    // Upload file page
    private FirstClassInfo firstClassInfo = new FirstClassInfo();

    // ... other private members and methods

    public void someMethodCallsThoseClasses(){

            new FirstClass(firstclassInfo);
            // other classes

    }

    public void allClassesCompleted(){
        // When all of the steps are completed, this will be executed

        // I would like to write uploaded file to the disk here
        File targetFile = new File(FirstClass.uploadLocation + firstclassInfo.getDiskName());

                    java.nio.file.Files.copy(
                            firstclassInfo.getStream(),
                            targetFile.toPath(),
                            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

         // It gives me File upload exception: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    }
}
```

Here is the FirstClass:

```
public class FirstClass {
    public static final String uploadLocation = "PATH TO FILE!";
    private FirstClassInfo firstclassInfo;
    private UploadFinishedHandler uploadFinishedHandler;

    public FirstClass (FirstClassInfo firstclassInfo){
        this.firstclassInfo= firstclassInfo;
    }

    // ... other methods


    // File upload method

    private void uploadFinish() {
        uploadFinishedHandler = (InputStream stream, String fileName, String mimeType, long length, int filesLeftInQueue) -> {
            // ... some methods
                firstclassInfo.setStream(stream);
            // ... some methods
        };
    }

}
```

And here is the FirstClassInfo:

```
public class FirstClassInfo{

    // ... other private members
    private String diskName;

    private InputStream stream;

    // getters and setters are below. Default getters and setters


}
```

I cannot access to the stream object inside FirstClassInfo, because the stream is closed once the upload is completed. However, I would like to reach the data and write it to the file at the last step, in `allClassesCompleted` method. What is the strategy that I should follow?

Comment: You  cannot use an InputStream for writing.. So you need to have an OutputStream for writing.

Comment: I have figured it out.

I'm reading to an InputStream. The caller class passes a reference to byte[], so the called class (FirstClass) converts InputStream to byte[].

Then, in the Caller class, I'm writing to a file via converting byte[] to OutputStream. Thank you for the method. This is the current implementation that I have. Maybe it could be better.

Outside of `uploadFinishedHandler `, the stream is closed, so I cannot think of any other method